# Objective-C sending a large dictionary as JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, post

I have a large dictionary (partial example below - there are 26 products in total) that I need to send back to a ColdFusion web service. I was able to make a connection to the web service and when checking the NSHTTPURLResponse statusCode I get 200, which indicates the service is receiving and returning something (right?) but when I check the return I get HTML results, part of which states an error:

```
coldfusion.runtime.MissingArgumentException: The PAJSONSTRING parameter to the setPurchaseAgreements function is required but was not passed in.
```

which to me seems that I am not setting the value for the variable PAJSONSTRING. So my question is how would I be able to pass this JSON to that variable? I thought of the query string but when that would end up passing somewhere between 5000 and 7000 characters depending on what the user is sending back. But I can't seem to find an example of how to set a parameter value using POST. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
PA =     {
        "CUSTOMER_ID" = xxxxxxx;
        "GROSS_GROWTH_NO_YF_FLU" = 39385;
        "GROSS_GROWTH_ONLINE_DISC" = 394;
        "GROSS_GROWTH_SALES" = 56500;
        "GROSS_PROJECTED_NO_YF_FLU" = 35805;
        "GROSS_PROJECTED_ONLINE_DISC" = 358;
        "GROSS_PROJECTED_SALES" = 52920;
        "GROSS_SALES" = 0;
        "GROSS_SALES_CUST_PRICE_LIST" = 0;
        "GROWTH_MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = 3509;
        "GROWTH_NET_SALES" = 56500;
        "GROWTH_NET_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 394;
        "GROWTH_PROJ_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 3509;
        "GROWTH_REBATE_AMT" = 3509;
        "GROWTH_REBATE_PCT" = 9;
        "MATCH_GRTH_REBATE_GRTH_SALES" = "";
        "MATCH_NET_SALES" = 49200;
        "MATCH_PROJ_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 35447;
        "MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = 3190;
        "MATCH_REBATE_NET_DISCOUNT_SLS" = "";
        "MTH_GRTH_RBT_GRTH_NET_DISC_SLS" = "";
        "NEW_PRICE_DISC_NET_DISC" = "";
        "ONLINE_DISCOUNT_PCT" = 1;
        "OPER_ID" = xxxxxx;
        "PA_CREATE_DT" = "2014-01-03 05:00:00 +0000";
        "PA_ID" = 0;
        "PA_NAME" = "Copy of 8";
        "PA_STATUS_ID" = 2;
        "PRICELIST_TYPE_ID" = 5;
        "PRICE_LIST_GROWTH_SALES" = "";
        "PRICE_LIST_PROJECTED_SALES" = "";
        "REBATE_ELG_PROD_COUNT" = 0;
        "SALES_ROSTER_ID" = 20016;
        "START_DT" = "2014-01-03 17:56:12 +0000";
        "STATUS_PRICE_LIST_NET_DISC_SLS" = "";
        "STATUS_PRICE_LIST_PROJ_SALES" = "";
        "TOTAL_GRTH_MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = "";
        "UPFRONT_DISCOUNT_PCT" = 0;
    };
    PRODUCTS =     (
                {
            "DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;
        },
                {
            "DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;

"DISCOUNT_DOSE_PRICE" = 8;
            "DISCOUNT_UNIT_PRICE" = 80;
            "GROWTH_DOSES" = 0;
            "GROWTH_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "LIST_DOSE_PRICE" = 0;
            "OPER_ID" = 20016;
            "PA_PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "PRODUCT_ID" = xxxxx;
            "SALES_PROJECTED" = 0;
            "SUGGESTED_DOSES" = 0;
            "USER_SELECTED_DOSES" = 0;
        }
    );
}
```

partial code...

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJSONData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

        NSString* urlString = SERVICE_SET_PA;

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];


        NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* responseError) {

            id results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            NSString* strResults = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            DDLogVerbose(@"%@", strResults);

            NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

            if (data.length > 0 && responseError == nil) {
                DDLogVerbose(@"%@", httpResponse.allHeaderFields);
                [self receivedData:data];
            } else if (data.length == 0 && error == nil) {
                [self emptyReply];
            } else if (responseError != nil) {
                [self displayError: error];
            }

        }];
```

Edit: Logging jsonData shows this (partial post):

```
<7b0a2020 22504122 203a207b 0a202020 20225041 5f494422 203a2030 2c0a2020 2020224d 41544348 5f475254 485f5245 42415445 5f475254 485f5341 4c455322 203a2022 222c0a20 20202022 50415f53 54415455 535f4944 22203a20 322c0a20 20202022 47524f57 54485f50 524f4a5f 53414c45 535f4e4f 5f59465f 464c5522 203a2033 3530392c...
```

Deserializing it and logging it show this (partial post):

```
PA =     {    
"CUSTOMER_ID" = 955728;
    "GROSS_GROWTH_NO_YF_FLU" = 39385;
    "GROSS_GROWTH_ONLINE_DISC" = 394;
    "GROSS_GROWTH_SALES" = 56500;
    "GROSS_PROJECTED_NO_YF_FLU" = 35805;
    "GROSS_PROJECTED_ONLINE_DISC" = 358;
    "GROSS_PROJECTED_SALES" = 52920;
    "GROSS_SALES" = 0;
    "GROSS_SALES_CUST_PRICE_LIST" = 0;
    "GROWTH_MATCH_REBATE_AMT" = 3509;
    "GROWTH_NET_SALES" = 56500;
    "GROWTH_NET_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 394;
    "GROWTH_PROJ_SALES_NO_YF_FLU" = 3509;
    ...
```

so at least to this extent it looks fine.

Comment: Did you check the JSON data gets created? What is the server expecting?

Comment: So presumably the server is expecting the data in a different format somehow. Possibly a different key in the JSON? What is `PAJSONSTRING`?

Comment: PAJSONSTRING is a variable that is expecting the JSON string. If it was a URL query it would look like http://www.someplace.com?PAJSONSTRING=MYJSONSTRING, I could rewrite my code to pass a string but I think it would be too long.

Comment: Are you using `FORM.PAJSONSTRING` ?

Comment: No, where would I use that?

Comment: The server - how is it trying to get the data you're passing. Your code and debugging of the app looks ok so what does the server expect and what does it get needs to be looked at.

Comment: I don't control that so I'll have to check with the developer on that end. Thanks for looking things over.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `AFNetworking` Framework (osx&ios).
(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Example (from documentation)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Or RestKit could be another good option depending on what the source data actually is...

Comment: I'll probably go that route but I'd like to understand the science behind the library all the same.